# Error message about unresolved dependencies when running PIP inside a Conda virtual env

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tensorflow, pip

I'm running a zsh shell on **Manjaro-stable** with a **Conda (4.10.1)** virtual environment activated with **Python 3.9.2** And when I try to install a package via `pip install` it sometimes returns an error message about unresolved dependencies. For example when I try to install Tensorflow:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pyxnat 1.4 requires future>=0.16, which is not installed.
nipype 1.6.0 requires filelock>=3.0.0, which is not installed.
```

I installed pip using `conda install pip` and `which pip` returns:

```
/home/gova/anaconda3/envs/drmdef/bin/pip
```

---

When I try to import Tensorflow via the shell, I get this echoed back at me:

```
Python 3.9.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 21 2021, 05:02:46) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
2021-04-17 18:21:18.145981: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-17 18:21:18.146004: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
INFO:tensorflow:Enabling eager execution
INFO:tensorflow:Enabling v2 tensorshape
INFO:tensorflow:Enabling resource variables
INFO:tensorflow:Enabling tensor equality
INFO:tensorflow:Enabling control flow v2
>>>
```

That means TensorFlow is indeed installed and importable. Those error messages aren't the problem since I haven't started to configure the system for TensorFlow. But anything regarding that would be also helpful.

---

**Why am I seeing that error message? Why isn't pip resolving all the unmet dependencies?
What can be done to solve this problem?**

Comment: Tensorflow is not yet officially supported under 3.9, so that may explain some of it.

Comment: I'm getting similar errors for other packages as well, under the same conditions.

Comment: These error messages do not cause any issue as long as you are using Tensorflow CPU version. These messages can be ignored if you not using GPU. Thanks!

Comment: Well... I'm using the `tensorflow` library, but it seems to be using the NVIDIA GPU. Ouput when running a sample pythone code:
 `2021-04-19 12:30:10.671336: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:` 
`pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce 940MX computeCapability: 5.0`